# Google OAuth giving 400 error: invalid request despite correct redirect URI

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sso

I am building a web app in Adalo (a no-code app builder) that I want to enable Google Single Sign On in. My issue is that every time I try to sign in to Google having began my journey within the Adalo previewer I get a "Error 400: invalid_request" error, and the error details say its an issue with my redirect URI. See attached image.

Google Sign In - error screen

[image]

What's weird is that if I try to sign in just entering the sign in URL in my browser then everything works fine so clearly its not an actual issue with my redirect URI. Anyone have any ideas why? People on the Adalo side don't seem to.

Comment: Hi, Does this answer your question [GOAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76767770/14886384)