# How to make a user backend, for other backends to use it, like googleoauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

this is my first post in the community, so I'll try to be brief, I need guidance for a project.
I have to develop a backend node in which it will create the user, update and the whole process that you already know, but now it gets complicated. this backend would be like a google, in which other backend applications connected to it to use its user system. I'm not sure if you understand, I'm creating some strategies for this demand, but if anyone knows how to do it or what strategies to use, it will already be a help. Thanks!

I thought about making an authentication scheme in which the backend user would send an ID and TOKEN, with that, another backend would log into the application and use the user scheme of the backedn user.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

##### As I can understand you need multiple backend for multiple services.

- As per my knowledge you can achieve that by [Microservice architecture](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-microservices-node-js/).
- And click on link for [Token based authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-jwt-expressjs).
- For **[Google Authentication](https://github.com/tirathsharma098/GoogleOAuth2.0)** visit link and open server folder in which you will get code for google OAuth2.0